# R Shiny Dynamic plotting to make 4 plots instead of 1

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to modify this code:

https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415

So that instead of 1 plot appearing, 4 plots will appear.

In the current code if `input$n = 1` you see 1 plot;

```
plot1
```

or `input$n=3` you see 3 plots:

```
plot1

plot2

plot3
```

I'd need to have 4 plots displayed in a 2 x 2 layout so that if `input$n = 1` you see

```
plot1A  plot1B
plot1C  plot1D
```

for `input$n = 2` you'd see;

```
plot1A  plot1B
plot1C  plot1D

plot2A  plot2B
plot2C  plot2D
```

for `input$n = 3` you'd see:

```
plot1A  plot1B
plot1C  plot1D

plot2A  plot2B
plot2C  plot2D

plot3A  plot3B
plot3C  plot3D
```

etc...

Can anyone modify that code so that the plots are shows 4 times in that same 2x2 framework that you see above

Here is what I came up with:

Here is my ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  sidebarPanel(

sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=5)
  ),

  mainPanel(
# This is the dynamic UI for the plots
h3("Heading 1"),
uiOutput("plots"),
h3("Heading 2"),
verbatimTextOutput("test")
  )
))
```

here is my server.r:

```
library("gridExtra")
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
      plot_output_list <- lapply(1:(input$n), function(i) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
        plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
      })

      # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
      # to display properly.
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
      do.call(grid.arrange,  plot_output_list)

  })##End outputplots

  #PrintPlots<- reactive({
  observe({
    max_plots<-length(getAugmentedTerms(input$Desk, input$Product, input$File1))

    #print(max_plots)
    # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
    # are visible on the web page.
    for (i in 1:max_plots) {
      # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
      # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
      # of when the expression is evaluated.
      local({
    my_i <- i
    plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

    p1<-qplot(1:10)

    p2<-qplot(1:10)

    p3<- qplot(1:10)

    p4<-qplot(1:10)



        output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({

         #grid.arrange(  arrangeGrob
          arrangeGrob(  p1, p2,p3,p4, ncol= 2)
       })#End RENDER PLOT
      })#END LOCAL
    }##### End FoR Loop
  })# END OF PRINT PLOTS

})# END OF ENERYTHING
```

BUT I am getting an error:

```
 Error in arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2) : input must be grobs!
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood your question.

By the way, if you use standard plots (as in your gist) you can simply use the par option.

```
output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
  par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  p1 = plot(...)
  p2 = plot(...)
  p3 = plot(...)
  p4 = plot(...)
})
```

When you use ggplot2 graphics, you can't set the par option and I don't know something similar already implemented in ggplot2.

By the way, I found [the multiplot() function](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

It seems to be what you are looking for. Please define multiplot function at the begin of your server.

R, before the call to `shinyServer()`. You can copy and paste the function in server.

R or keep the script clean and save them to a different script (e.g. `functions.R`). In this case, do not forget to read the function with `source("functions.R")`.

In your reactive environment you'll produce the four plots and then print them together:

```
output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
  qp1 <- qplot(1:my_i, 1:my_i)
  qp2 <- qplot(1:my_i, 1:my_i)
  qp3 <- qplot(1:my_i, 1:my_i)
  qp4 <- qplot(1:my_i, 1:my_i)
  multiplot(qp1, qp2, qp3, qp4, cols=2)
})
```

I hope I reply to your question.

Comment: These are not standard plots because they are rendered dynamically. Do you know how to modify the code to show the dynamic charts?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you'd like to plot. As you seen in my code above, plots are already dynamically rendered: they depends from input value my_i.